# what should I make my package if my domain has a dash?

Tags: oop

The convention for packages is your domain name. Dashes are sometimes not allowed in package names. So if your domain name has a dash what should you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "official" convention in Java is to replace it with an underscore.

From (an older version of) the spec:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. Here are some suggested conventions for dealing with these
>   situations:
>
> If the domain name contains a hyphen, or any other special character
>   not allowed in an identifier (§3.8), convert it into an underscore. If
>   any of the resulting package name components are keywords (§3.9) then
>   append underscore to them. If any of the resulting package name
>   components start with a digit, or any other character that is not
>   allowed as an initial character of an identifier, have an underscore
>   prefixed to the component.

Comment: What spec is this from? The OP doesn't indicate a language.

Comment: I didn't specify language because I thought I might run into it in other languages as well. It is Java where I am seeing it now tho.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is an option I've used before, but otherwise, just concatenate.